# FreeBSD - Is it possible to create a clone of a snapshot in a different disk for improved performance?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, iscsi, snapshot, clone

I am a new to FreeBSD and want to make a virtual disk service via iSCSI.
I create snapshots of a dataset on the same disks, however I would like to create clones on a different disk like a NVMe drive to speed up on writing. Is it possible?

I am concerning possible performance decrese when reading(dataset) /writing(clones) occur on the same disk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can’t do what you want.

Yes, you can improve write performance of the certain workload types and patterns by adding NVMe-based L2ARC and ZIL to your configuration.

This is a good place to start!

https://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFSTuningGuide

Comment: Hi El. Thank you so much for your answer and I will follow the guide in the link. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If using ZFS, this is not possible but not even required or useful: ZFS is designed for keeping full performance even when dealing with many snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with zfs send/recv

A clone when the destination does not exist:

```
zfs send -R -c "/tank1/vol1@2023-11-12" | zfs receive -u "/tank2/vol@2023-11-12"
```

You can update the clone incremental later on with `zfs send -i`